# Extending the Eclipse HTML editor to ignore a specific, unknown, tag

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to extend the HTML editor from Eclipse to allow a specific tag, named "sly", to be ignored by validation. I have tried defining a couple of validators using the Eclipse extensions points, but that has not worked out.

**plugin.xml**

```
<extension id="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.sightly.internal.Validator" name="Sightly Validator" point="org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2">
  <validator
        build="true"
        class="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.sightly.internal.Validator"
        sourceid="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.sightly.internal.htmlSyntaxTotalValidator"
        manual="true"
        version="1"
        markerId="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.validationMarker">
     <include>
        <rules>
           <contentType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource"></contentType>
           <fileext caseSensitive="false" ext="html"/>
        </rules>
     </include>
     <group id="org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.structuredModelGroup"/>
  </validator>
```

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation">
    <validator
        scope="total"
        class="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.sightly.internal.TotalValidator"
        id="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.sightly.internal.htmlSyntaxTotalValidator">
        <contentTypeIdentifier
            id="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource">
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_DEFAULT"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_DECLARATION"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.html.HTML_COMMENT"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.XML_DEFAULT"/>
            <partitionType id="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ST_DEFAULT"/>
        </contentTypeIdentifier>
    </validator>
</extension>
```

**Java classes**

```
public class Validator extends HTMLValidator {

    @Override
    protected HTMLValidationReporter getReporter(IReporter reporter, IFile file, IDOMModel model) {
        return new ValidatorReporter(this, reporter, file, model);
    }
}

public class ValidatorReporter extends HTMLValidationReporter {
    ValidatorReporter(IValidator owner, IReporter reporter, IFile file, IStructuredModel model) {
        super(owner, reporter, file, model);
    }

        @Override
        public void report(ErrorInfo info) {
            int targetType = info.getTargetType();
            if (targetType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && info.getState() == 11) {
                String name = info.getHint();
                if ("sly".equals(name) ) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            super.report(info);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell my validators are being called, but they are not overriding the HTML validators. Can I somehow override the default HTML validators or must I ask the users to disable HTML validation?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this commit: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sling-commits/201510.mbox/%3C20151013121043.9AD5E3A043F@svn01-us-west.apache.org%3E

Comment: @HelmutGranda - actually, I made that commit :-) But thanks for reminding me that I should post an answer to this question

Comment: Great! so how do we get that patch in place? ;) I was looking for something similar and I am just using validation rules to avoid the warnings.

Comment: I suggest you start looking at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/tooling/ide/eclipse-sightly-core/ and http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/tooling/ide/eclipse-sightly-ui/ until I get a proper answer in place.